# Dialog Theme.DeviceDefault forced

Tags: android, dialog, styles, themes

I am making a dialog, where I want to show EditTexts and Radio buttons.

But the theme is not applying. According to Layout Inspector, the Views have the correct theme applied (shown "forced"), but there is "android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault()", which is also "forced" (it is shown above my style, if that matters).

The problem is, that the Views look differently on different APIs, which I guess is caused by that DeviceDefault. I have not set anywhere anything about DeviceDefault, but it applies to all my Dialogs.

Any idea how to dissmiss it? Thanks.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem right now. I have cardview which on layout inspector and emulator looks correct but on the device it has a dark theme for some reason.

Comment: Could you share your code, please?

Comment: @ErnestZamelczyk share appropriate code in order to be able to understand your issue.

Answer (score 1):

About **Theme.DeviceDefaul** in Android:

There are many Themes available for Android devices.

- **Theme**: the default for the earliest versions of Android up to 2.3 Gingerbread(10)
- **Theme.Holo**: from Android 3.0 Honeycomb (11)
- **Theme.Material**: from Android 5.0 Lollipop (21)
- **Theme.DeviceDefault**: from Android 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich (14), a theme that can be customized by the device manufacturer. It represents the native look of the device.

**Specifying different themes:**

Android's resource overlay system allows to specify styles based on device API level, via Android Studio will setup for you.

For example different versions of a style in *res/values-v11* and *res/values-v21*.

*/res/values/styles.xml* is applied to every device and serves as base:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light"/>
</resources>
```

*/res/values-v11/styles.xml* is loaded on all devices that have API level 11 and above (including those that are 21 and above):

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light"/>
</resources>
```

*/res/values-v21/styles.xml* is loaded on all devices that have API level 21 and above:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light"/>
</resources>
```

*AndroidManifest.xml* is the place where the custom theme is put to use.

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Every API level has its own default theme and since you use the default theme to your app, android adjusts the theme depending on the API level which will be different on each device. Just remember that just the element of which you add the style attribute to gets the specified style attributes. The child objects or child view does not get the style attribute. If you want child views to inherit styles, instead apply the style with the `android:theme` attribute.

The problem is probolby linked to where, and how, you apply your own theme. 
You should apply your theme in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. If you apply your theme in the `application tag` or the `activity tag`, you cover different parts of the application with your theme. What you have done is hard to say without any code present.

You should apply your theme to one of the following sections of the file.

To cover the whole application

```
<manifest ... >
    <application android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" ... >
    </application>
</manifest>
```

To cover just one activity

```
<manifest ... >
    <application ... >
        <activity android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" ... >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

If a view supports only some of the attributes that you declared in the style that you created, it then only applies those attributes and ignores the ones it does not support.

If you want to change the default style and colors, you can override them in the `styles.xml` file. Search for the item name that represents the color value and change corresponding value in the `res/values/colors.xml` file.

I hope this information will solv your problem, but as I said, it this really hard so exactly say without the code present.